# node mysql2 Incorrect arguments statement

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-mysql2

this is my function.  If I remove the `?` and enter the info manually it executes, I would assume this is how you pass in parameters.  is this correct?  If i console log the params they all work, I am assuming the way the params are been passed down

```js
async function getMultiple(page = 1){
    const offset = helper.getOffset(page, config.listPerPage);
    const rows = await db.query(
        'SELECT id, quote, author FROM quote LIMIT ?,?',
        [offset, config.listPerPage]
    );
    const data = helper.emptyOrRows(rows);
    const meta = {page};

    return {
        data,
        meta
    }
}

module.exports = {
  getMultiple
}
```

Comment: Are you certain `helper.getOffset()` has returned a value by the time you try an use it in `db.query()`? What happens if you make it asynchronous as well and `await` its return before you proceed to the query?

Comment: @dusthaines yea, if i console.log offset i get a value, before it goes to db.query.   its strange.

Comment: And if you console.log `config.listPerPage` you see a value as well? Your query looks ok so worth confirming that listPerPage value is coming from the config module as expected.

Comment: @dusthaines yea, its also returning a value before going to db.query as expected.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the mysql version I had installed (8.0.23) has a problem with prepared statements (or a different way).   I had to downgrade to less than that and it worked as expected.   I downgraded to 5.7